# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ya existe la columna «user_id» en la relación «django_admin_log»

Tags: python, django, backend

actualmente estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Django 2.0.2, pero al realizar las migraciones de mis modelos obtengo él siguiente error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ya existe la columna «user_id» en la relación «django_admin_log»
```

Este es todo lo que muestra la consola:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 122, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
field,
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 421, in add_field
self.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 117, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ya existe la columna «user_id» en la relación «django_admin_log»
```

Este es el modelo que me están dando problemas:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Perfil(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    nombre = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name='Nombre',
        help_text='Ingrese su nombre'
    )
    apellidos = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name='Apellido',
        help_text='Ingrese su Apellido'
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='avatars/',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Avatar'
    )
    cumpleaños = models.DateField(
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Fecha de nacimiento',
        help_text='Seleccione su fecha de nacimiento'
    )
    universidad = models.ForeignKey(
        'principal.Universidad',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Universidad',
        help_text='Seleccione la universidad a la que pertenece'
    )
    facultad = models.ForeignKey(
        'principal.Facultad',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Facultad',
        help_text='Seleccione su Facultad'
    )
    carrera = models.ForeignKey(
        'principal.Carrera',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Carrera',
        help_text='Seleccione su carrera'
    )
    publicaciones = models.ForeignKey(
        'evaluaciones.Publicacion',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Publicaciones',
        help_text=''
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.usuario.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Perfil'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Perfiles'
```

Mi intención es usar el modelo de Usuario que trae Django por defecto y agregarle otros campos, pero no se ejecutan las migraciones por ese error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy casi seguro que el error te lo da porque el migrate quiere crear tablas o relaciones que ya existen. Seguramente ya has hecho un `python manage.py migrate` que te falló en determinado momento pero se han creado las tablas del admin y quiere crearlos de nuevo y eso da un error en la migración.

Primero probaría con hacer un `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial` 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#django.db.migrations.Migration.initial

Si no llega a funcionar tambien podes borrar la base de dato (si es posible hacerlo) hagas de nuevo el `python manage.py makemigrations` y luego el `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Gracias, no probé el comando, pero lo solucioné con borrar la base de datos, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puede que sea un poco tarde, pero a mi me resultó el borrar la tabla que da problemas, y crearla nuevamente vacía, sin columnas ni nada.

luego ya aplicar otra vez `python manage.py makemigrations` y `python manage.py migrate`

Saludos